# How to show all the names of three or less authors in text?

Tags: natbib, apa-style, author-number

I am using the article document class and the natbib package. When I cite 3 or more authors, this is shown as FirstAuthor et al. I want to change this such that when I have one, two or three authors, all their names are shown in text, while if I have 4 or more authors, this would then be shown as FirstAuthor et al.

Is there a simple way to change the truncation of authors?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I am using bibliography style ``apa``

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you use `biblatex` with  these options:

```
\usepackage[natbib, maxcitenames=3, mincitenames=11, style=apa]{biblatex}
```

The `natbib` option is for compatibility with natbib commands.

Note the default backend for biblatex is `biber`. You may specify in the options `backend=bibtex` but you'll lose some functionalities.

Comment: Do you have max and min cite-names switched here? Or is there some special behavior here I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 9):

You would like to print the **full author list**, thus use citations with star `*`, such as `\citet*`, `citep*` under the package `natbib`. See below for more info.

```
\citet     #textual citations, print the abbreviated author list
\citet*    #textual citations, print the full author list

\citep     #parenthetical citations, print the abbreviated author list
\citep*    #parenthetical citations, print the full author list

\citealt    #the same as \citet but without any parentheses.
\citealp    #the same as \citep but without any parentheses.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these command: `\citet*{}` or `\citep*{}` and for more extended citation you can use `\citealt*{}` or`\citealp*{}`.

According to natbib documentation, these commands show all authors and not just the abbreviated one

[Natbib Documentation](http://authortools.aas.org/aastex/natbib.pdf)

Comment: According to the `natbib` user guide, the "starred" citing method works only if the bibliography style is compatible with it. You should ask the OP which bibliography style is in use.

Comment: I am using bibliography style  ``apa``. ``\citet*{}`` does not work in in this case.