# No Et Al. for Three Authors with apalike and natbib

Tags: natbib

I use `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` and `\usepackage{natbib}` together. I need **One, Two, and Three (1234)** rather than **One et al. (1234)** by default for `\citet` and `\citep`—not `\citet*` or `\citep*`. I tried to use `\usepackage{biblatex}` following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244841), but it caused a problem similar to [the bibhang already defined problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375813). How can I do this using the following MWE?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
\citet{asdf}
\bibliography{asdf}
\end{document}
```

```
@article{asdf,
    title={asdf},
    author={One, One and Two, Two and Three, Three},
    journal={asdf},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    pages={1--2},
    year={1234}
}
```

Comment: If you're using `apalike` and `natbib` you're *not* using `biblatex`. If you're making this many changes (as in your previous question) you may want to switch to `biblatex` since it's generally easier to modify (no `.bst` files).  I would recommend `ext-authoryear` style as a beginning (not the `biblatex` `apa`, style which is not designed to be modified since it implements the exact APA style).

Comment: Switching to ```biblatex``` seems to be a bit costly—is this kind of ```apalike```-```natbib``` combination deprecated?

Comment: No, but making lots of changes isn't ideal.  Maybe you should use `makebst` to generate your own `.bst` file instead.

Comment: My apologies to bother you, but may I ask your help again if this problem can also be solved by changing ```apalike``` too? I am checking ```biblatex``` now, but it seems quite different from what I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apalike` is not one of the 'native' `natbib` styles. It is much older than `natbib` and does not support all of `natbib`'s features (for example it does not support the starred commands `\citet*` and `\citep*`).

The desired output can be achieved by editing the `.bst` file.

1. Locate `apalike.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich apalike.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `apalike-three.bst`, say (the license of `apalike.bst` requires you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Find `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` (ll. 841-587) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
    FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
    { 's :=
      s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      s num.names$ duplicate$ duplicate$
      #3 >
        { pop$ pop$ " et~al." * }
        { #2 <
            'pop$
            { #2 =
              { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                  { " et~al." * }
                  { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
                if$ }
              { ", " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ *
                s #3 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                  { " et~al." * }
                  { ", and " * s #3 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
                if$}
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
   ```
5. Find `FUNCTION {calc.label}` (ll. 896-912) and replace the complete function definition with

   ```
    FUNCTION {calc.label}
    { type$ "book" =
      type$ "inbook" =
      or
        'author.editor.key.label
        { type$ "proceedings" =
            'editor.key.label                       % apalike ignores organization
            'author.key.label                       % for labeling and sorting
          if$
        }
      if$
      "("                                                  % these three lines are
      *                                                     % for apalike, which
      year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$          % uses all four digits
      *
      ")" *
      'label :=
    }
   ```

   This change is necessary to avoid `natbib` misparsing the name list.
6. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
7. Use `\bibliographystyle{apalike-three}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/e3d3ed6ebc93b5e05d6394813f5ad3e5

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-three}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{asdf3,
  title   = {asdf},
  author  = {One, One and Two, Two and Three, Three},
  journal = {asdf},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--2},
  year    = {1234},
}
@article{asdf2,
  title   = {asdf},
  author  = {One, One and Two, Two},
  journal = {asdf},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--2},
  year    = {1234},
}
@article{asdf1,
  title   = {asdf},
  author  = {One, One},
  journal = {asdf},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--2},
  year    = {1234},
}
@article{asdf4,
  title   = {asdf},
  author  = {One, One and Two, Two and Three, Three and Four, Four},
  journal = {asdf},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--2},
  year    = {1234},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citet{asdf1}

\citet{asdf2}

\citet{asdf3}

\citet{asdf4}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: One (1234)//One and Two (1234)//One, Two, and Three (1234)//One et al. (1234)]

Comment: Thanks a lot—this was why ```\citet*``` and ```\citep*``` don't work for my case.