# No et al. for three authors with apalike and natbib, and also long year

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I am having the same issue as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559571/no-et-al-for-three-authors-with-apalike-and-natbib). I adopted the solution in the posted answer. That solution solves the "et al." problem.

However, I would also like to allow years with more than 4 characters.

When I modify the 4 to a 20 in this line:

```
year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
```

I get side effects like years missing from some citations.

How can I modify the syntax in the earlier answer to get the behavior that I want?